# PDFTron full api is not getting loaded in WebViewer

Tags: pdf, pdftron, pdf-form

I am trying to get the full api of PDFTron working from the WEbViewer. I followed the steps in the link below.
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/full-api/setup/

But I am getting the error given below in console while loading the webviewer.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Full version of PDFNetJS has not been loaded. Please pass the "fullAPI: true" option in your WebViewer constructor to use the PDFNet APIs.
    at Object.get (CoreControls.js:1694)
    at z.docViewer.on ((index):43)
    at CoreControls.js:398
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at z.O (CoreControls.js:398)
    at CoreControls.js:213
```

[image]

[image]

This is my code.

```
         WebViewer({
        path: 'WebViewer-6.0.2/lib', // path to the PDFTron 'lib' folder on your server
        type: 'html5',
         initialDoc: 'forms/local.pdf',  // You can also use documents on your server
         fullAPI: true,
      }, document.getElementById('viewer'))
      .then(instance => {
        const docViewer = instance.docViewer;
        const annotManager = instance.annotManager;

    const Annotations = instance.Annotations;
    Annotations.ChoiceWidgetAnnotation.FORCE_SELECT=true;
    const Actions = instance.Actions;
      docViewer.on('documentLoaded', async () => {
      const  PDFNet = instance.PDFNet;
      await PDFNet.Initialize();
      // This part requires the full API: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/full-api/setup/
      alert('async');
      const doc = docViewer.getDocument();
      // Get document from worker
      const pdfDoc = await doc.getPDFDoc();
      pdfDoc.getAcroForm().putBool("NeedAppearances", true);
      });
    docViewer.on('documentLoaded', () => {
 docViewer.on('annotationsLoaded', () => {
      const annotations = annotManager.getAnnotationsList();
      annotations.forEach(annot => {
      console.log('fieldName => '+annot.fieldName);

});
    });
```

Please help me resolve this.

**EDIT**

Modified the code as suggested by @Andy.
The updated code in index.html file looks like below,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Basic WebViewer</title>
</head>

<!-- Import WebViewer as a script tag -->
<script src='WebViewer-6.0.2/lib/webviewer.min.js'></script>


<body>
  <div id='viewer' style='width: 1024px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto;'>
  <script>
  WebViewer({
    path: 'WebViewer-6.0.2/lib', // path to the PDFTron 'lib' folder on your server
    type: 'html5',
     fullAPI: true,
     // licenseKey: 'Insert commercial license key here after purchase',
  }, document.getElementById('viewer'))
  .then(async instance => {
  const { Annotations, Tools, CoreControls, PDFNet, PartRetrievers, docViewer, annotManager } = instance;
    await PDFNet.Initialize();
        Annotations.ChoiceWidgetAnnotation.FORCE_SELECT=true;
    const Actions = instance.Actions;
      docViewer.on('documentLoaded', async () => {
      // This part requires the full API: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/full-api/setup/
      const doc = docViewer.getDocument();
      // Get document from worker
      const pdfDoc = await doc.getPDFDoc();
      const acroFrom = await pdfDoc.getAcroForm();
      acroform.putBool("NeedAppearances", true);
      });
    instance.loadDocument('forms/test.pdf');
  });
</script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am loading the file from a http server in my project folder.

```
 http-server -a localhost -p 7080
```

Unfortunately, I  am getting the same error.

```
Error: Full version of PDFNetJS has not been loaded. Please pass the "fullAPI: true" option in your WebViewer constructor to use the PDFNet APIs.
```

[image]

We are currently evaluating PDFTron, so the licenseKey option is not passed in the WebViewer constructor.

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried out the code you have provided and was still not able to reproduce the issue you are encountering. I do typically perform the initialize outside WebViewer events so the initialization occurs only once:

```js
WebViewer(...)
    .then(instance => {
        const { Annotations, Tools, CoreControls, PDFNet, PartRetrievers, docViewer } = instance;
        const annotManager = docViewer.getAnnotationManager();

        await PDFNet.initialize(); // Only needs to be initialized once

        docViewer.on('documentLoaded', ...);
        docViewer.on('annotationsLoaded', ...);
});
```

Also, I noticed that you attach an an event handler to `annotationsLoaded` every time `documentLoaded` is triggered. I am not sure if that is intentional or desirable but this can lead to the handler triggering multiple times (when switching documents).

This may not matter but instead of using `initialDoc`, you could try `instance.loadDocument` after the initialize instead.

```js
await PDFNet.initialize();

docViewer.on('documentLoaded', ...);
docViewer.on('annotationsLoaded', ...);

instance.loadDocument('http://...');
```

There is one last thing to mention about the full API. The APIs will return a promise most of the time as the result so you will have to `await` the return value most of the time.

```js
const acroFrom = await pdfDoc.getAcroForm();
// You can await this too. Especially if you need a reference to the new bool object that was
acroform.putBool("NeedAppearances", true);
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for looking into this. I have updated the code. But still facing the issue. Added the latest code in the question post itself.

Comment: we are using the trial version of the PDFTron webviewer as we are evaluating it. Does this cause the issue?

Comment: After taking a look and trying out the HTML/JavaScript you provided. I noticed that your call to `PDFNet.Initialize` is slightly incorrect. The call should be lowercase: `PDFNet.initialize`. The JS API should be camelcase in most cases.

Comment: here there is an exameple https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/full-api/setup/